# How do I handle UnboundLocal Error in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a list of dictionaries into a dictionary of lists.

Example:

```
sample_1=[{"Country":"USA","State":"Florida","Population":120,"Area":120},{"Country":"USA","State":"Texas","Population":240,"Area":240}]
```

This is the function that I have to convert the above list of dictionaries into dictionary of lists.

```
def one_dict(list_dict):
    keys=list_dict[0].keys()
    out_dict={key:[]}
    for dict_ in list_dict:
        for key, value in dict_.items():
            out_dict[key].append(value)
    return out_dict
```

When I call the one_dict function with one_dict(sample_1), I get an UnboundLocal Error for Local variable key

Comment: You named the variable `keys`, and tried to read from `key` to initialize `out_dict={key:[]}`. You don't assign to `key` until you reach the inner loop. You probably want to do `out_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)`, optionally changing the return to `return dict(out_dict)` so you return a plain `dict`, not a `defaultdict(list)`.

Comment: What do you expect `key` to be in `out_dict={key:[]}`?

Comment: key in out_dict should be the Keys that I get from sample_1 list. So Country, State, Population and Area should be the keys.

Comment: That is because you are using variable `key` before declaring it.